# ColdFusion - How to get only the URL's in this block of text?

Tags: regex, coldfusion, railo, cfml

How can I extract **only** the URL's from the given block of text?

```
background(http://w1.sndcdn.com/f15ikDS9X_m.png)
background-image(http://w1.sndcdn.com/5ikDIlS9X_m.png)
background('http://w1.sndcdn.com/m1kDIl9X_m.png')
background-image('http://w1.sndcdn.com/fm15iIlS9X_m.png')
background("http://w1.sndcdn.com/fm15iklS9X_m.png")
background-image("http://w1.sndcdn.com/m5iIlS9X_m.png")
```

Perhaps Regex would work, but I'm not advanced enough to work it out!

Many thanks!
Mikey

Answer (score 4):

You're over-thinking the problem - all you need to do is match the URLs, which is a simple match:

```
rematch('\bhttps?:[^)''"]+',input)
```

That'll work based on the input provided - might need tweaking if different input used.

(e.g. You can optionally add a `\s` into the char class if that might be a factor.)

The regex itself is simple:

```
\bhttps?:  ## look for http: or https: with no alphanumeric chars beforehand.

[^)'"]+    ## match characters that are NOT ) or ' or "
           ## match as many as possible, at least one required.
```

If this is matching false positives, you can of course look for a more refined URL regex, such as [these](http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex).

Answer (score 2):

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/zY5cT5)

`background(?:-image)?\((["']?)(?<url>http.*)\1\)`

Explanation:

- `background(?:-image)?` -> It matches background or background-image (without grouping)
- `\(` -> matches a literal parentheses
- `(["']?)` -> matches if there is a `' or " or VOID` before the url
- `(?<url>http.*)` -> matches the url
- `\1\)` -> matches the grouped (third line of this explanation) and then a literal parentheses

Comment: Hi, thanks for this. The demo looks to be working, but I get the following error in Railo CF: "Invalid Syntax Closing [)] for function [REFIND] not found". Think something needs escaping?

Comment: That's because `(?<url>...)` is a named group, which doesn't exist in Apache ORO.

Comment: I didn't really know that, but if is what @Peter says, just remove the `?<url>` and tell me if it works to edit it.

Comment: Well, the expression will match, but it'll also require fiddle-arsing about to get group 2 from the match (CF's implementation is crappy and doesn't make extracting groups easy), and there's a much simpler way, just by matching URLs directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an answer without regular expressions, something like this will work.

```
YourString = "background(http://w1.sndcdn.com/f15ikDS9X_m.png)";
YourString = ListLast(YourString, "("); // yields http://w1.sndcdn.com/f15ikDS9X_m.png)
YourString = replace(YourString, ")", "");  // http://w1.sndcdn.com/f15ikDS9X_m.png
```

Since you are doing it more than once, you can make it a function.  Also, you might need some other replace commands to handle the quotes that are in some of your strings.

Having said all that, getting a regex to work would be better.

Comment: The question states it's a block of text - i.e. there are multiple URLs involved, not just one - otherwise doing `ListLast(input,'()"''')` could be a simple but effective solution.